# How should I go about refitting the seal under this interior door?

Tags: doors, sealing

The plastic draught/sealing strip underneath the front door of my UK flat (a non-external door to the common hallway) has become partly detached due to having mail pushed under it – photo below.

I'm not sure if this strip was originally glued or just tucked into a recess in the door (which, for what it's worth, was new in 2015), but I would like to know how I would go about reattaching it, and in particular whether it's possible to do so without removing the door from its hinges.

[image: Partly detached seal visible under interior door]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can surmise it is difficult to see under the door to evaluate what is going on with this plastic strip. Even if you had a good understanding of how the seal was originally secured in place it would be extremely difficult to get tools and possible supplies up under the door to work the seal back into place.

So it really comes down to taking the door off its hinges and setting it down on it's side so that you can inspect and take action to fix the problem. Once things are more fully understood you are in a lot better position to take the next steps actions.

Depending upon the situation be prepared that it may be necessary to re-hang and remove the door at least one additional time if it is necessary to procure supplies or delay the actual repair work.

Comment: Thank you – this is solid advice, particularly the part about potentially re-hanging twice. A tip borne out of bitter experience, I imagine!

Comment: Not really bitter at all. It is more about patience and eventual satisfaction that comes from properly fixing a problem like this without having to pay someone else to do it.

Comment: I'll add, depending on your door hinges, many have a PIN that can be quickly removed with a punch and a hammer rather that taking out 8 or 12 screws. https://cdn2.tmbi.com/TFH/Step-By-Step/FH07APR_REMDOO_01.JPG

Comment: The weatherstripping is coming loose for a reason...it may be binding on the piece attached to the floor, (or it may have been drug across a towel or something on the floor.) if it's the piece on the floor, I'd install the piece on the bottom of the door, then remove (carefully) the piece on the floor and re-set it by sliding it up to the door (in the closed position) and re-securing it to the floor. It may be too snug now which causes it to stick and pull loose.

Comment: Thanks all. @LeeSam: It's mail being pushed under the door that caused it to detach – it has good clearance otherwise.

Comment: There are other more heavy duty types of weatherstripping that will withstand the daily reckless abuse by a no good mailman. Google: "PEMKO weatherstripping." and search "door bottoms". They are one of the largest manufacturers. You may have to cut the bottom of the door a bit, but there's lots of options. Or you could borrow my Doberman and chain him up by the door. You might not get any mail, but that weatherstripping would stay on.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Michaels answer.

depending on your door hinges, many have a PIN that can be quickly removed with a punch and a hammer rather that taking out 8 or 12 screws.

[image]